# Bar Chart with Wide Format Data Fails With Data of Type datetime.time or datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, timedelta, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart of values of type `datetime.time` (alternatively `datetime.timedelta`) using `plotly`, but with no success.

I follow the example "Bar charts with Wide Format Data
" given in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/%22). I just convert the values to `datetime.time`:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()

wide_df["gold"] = wide_df["gold"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["bronze"] = wide_df["bronze"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["silver"] = wide_df["silver"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)

wide_df
```

Output:

```
nation  gold    silver  bronze
0   South Korea 00:24:00    00:13:00    00:11:00
1   China   00:10:00    00:15:00    00:08:00
2   Canada  00:09:00    00:12:00    00:12:00
```

The plotting the data ....

```
fig = px.bar(wide_df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

... results in:

[image]

Using `timedelta` instead of `time` results in a similar plot. I also tried using `px.timeline` but this chart only supports `datetime`. I want to see a stacked bar chart of values `datetime.time` or better `timedeltas`.

However, I need to see a stacked bar chart as in the example of the documentation (see below), **except with data of type `datetime.time` or `datetime.timedelta` on the y-axis**.

[image]

##### Question in short:

**How can I create the same stacked bar plot as in the documentation but with `timedelta`-values in the y-axis, i.e., in the format (HH:MM:SS)?**

##### The workarounds, I already tried:

Assuming to have data with values of type `timedelta`, i.e.,

```
import datetime
wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()
wide_df["gold"] = wide_df["gold"].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["bronze"] = wide_df["bronze"].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["silver"] = wide_df["silver"].apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df
```

```
nation  gold    silver  bronze
0   South Korea 0 days 00:24:00 0 days 00:13:00 0 days 00:11:00
1   China   0 days 00:10:00 0 days 00:15:00 0 days 00:08:00
2   Canada  0 days 00:09:00 0 days 00:12:00 0 days 00:12:00
```

I convert it to seconds in (integer format):

```
wide_df["gold"] = wide_df["gold"].apply(lambda t: t.seconds)
wide_df["silver"] = wide_df["silver"].apply(lambda t: t.seconds)
wide_df["bronze"] = wide_df["bronze"].apply(lambda t: t.seconds)
```

Then, I plot it and adjust the y-axis:

```
fig = px.bar(wide_df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input")
tickvals = [0, 600, 1200, 2400, 3000, 3600]
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=[datetime.timedelta(seconds=tv) for tv in tickvals], title="Duration")
fig.show()
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Object of type timedelta is not JSON serializable
```

To avoid this error, I use the datatype `datetime.time` instead:

```
fig = px.bar(wide_df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input")
tickvals = [0, 600, 1200, 2400, 3000, 3600]
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=[datetime.time(hour=int(tv/60/60), minute=int(tv/60%60)) for tv in tickvals], title="Duration")
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

This shows the plot I want to have, except that also the hover data needs manipulation to show the values in the format of HH:MM:SS and not seconds as an integer value.
Plus, I'd expect `px.bar` to accept `timedelta` values directly.

Comment: Another remark, if you want to get like the desired figure, where is the time in this figure countries in the x-axis and count on the y-axis?

Comment: As I just edited the question now, I'd need to see the same figure as in the documentation but with time formatted data and also time format displayed in the y-axis as HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Still not understood, try to draw it by painter, how do you stack bars based on time?!

Comment: Do you mean the y-axis will be the sum of minutes like that: 00:20, 00:40, 01:00, 01:20, 01:40?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the current date format fails, so it can be converted to a stacked bar chart by converting it to seconds. Finally, correct the scale on the y-axis.

```
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

wide_df = px.data.medals_wide()

wide_df["gold"] = wide_df["gold"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["bronze"] = wide_df["bronze"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)
wide_df["silver"] = wide_df["silver"].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(minute=x), convert_dtype=True)

wide_df["gold"] = wide_df["gold"].apply(lambda x: (x.hour * 60 + x.minute) * 60 + x.second)
wide_df["bronze"] = wide_df["bronze"].apply(lambda x: (x.hour * 60 + x.minute) * 60 + x.second)
wide_df["silver"] = wide_df["silver"].apply(lambda x: (x.hour * 60 + x.minute) * 60 + x.second)

fig = px.bar(wide_df, x='nation', y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input", barmode='stack')

fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,600,1200,1800,2400,3000], ticktext=[0,10,20,30,40,50], title='hour')
fig.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**
If we wanted to represent the data as a time series, it would be a horizontal stacked graph, but we used a timeline to create the graph by converting it to the required data frame format for the timeline.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="South Korea", Start='2022-11-16 00:37:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:47:00', Resource="Bronze"),
    dict(Task="South Korea", Start='2022-11-16 00:24:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:37:00', Resource="Silver"),
    dict(Task="South Korea", Start='2022-11-16 00:00:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:24:00', Resource="Gold"),
    dict(Task="China", Start='2022-11-16 00:25:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:33:00', Resource="Bronze"),
    dict(Task="China", Start='2022-11-16 00:10:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:25:00', Resource="Silver"),
    dict(Task="China", Start='2022-11-16 00:00:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:10:00', Resource="Gold"),
    dict(Task="Canada", Start='2022-11-16 00:21:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:33:00', Resource="Bronze"),
    dict(Task="Canada", Start='2022-11-16 00:09:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:21:00', Resource="Silver"),
    dict(Task="Canada", Start='2022-11-16 00:00:00', Finish='2022-11-16 00:09:00', Resource="Gold"),
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed", title_text='Nation')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution proposal! However, I need to see the y-axis in the format of time. I.e., [HH:MM:SS]. Following your solution, I'd have to use ``update_yaxis`` for casting the integer values into time format. I guess this could be a solution but it would be much cleaner if ``px.bar`` accepted the ``time`` format